# Injecting a Logger into an Ejb using CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I'm struggling a bit to put together what I thought was a simple task.
I have a Stateless Singleton Bean, that I'm going to use as a "loader" for my app.
The bean is included in a Jar (loader.jar) file and resides in the lib folder of my EAR.

In the root of the EAR resides another jar, containing the implementation of a Stateless Session Bean that is going to be used by my application.

Then I've created a small logger class, which actually wraps log4j:

```
    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
    import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
    import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
    import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
    import javax.inject.Named;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    public class LoggerFactory {
        private Logger logger;

        public LoggerFactory(){
            logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
        }

        @Produces Logger getLogger(InjectionPoint caller){
            return Logger.getLogger(caller.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
        }
    }
```

Then I've placed this inside a jar, that I've named as utils.jar. In this jar, following CDI specifications, I've created inside the META-INF folder an empty beans.xml file.
The utils.jar resides in the lib folder of my EAR.

Now, in the stateless Singleton Bean I've mentioned before (the loader)

I've wrote just this

```
    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.ejb.Singleton;
    import javax.ejb.Startup;
    import javax.inject.Inject;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    @Startup
    @Singleton
    public class Core {
        @Inject 
        private Logger logger;

        @PostConstruct
        void init(){
            logger.info("Core started");
        }
    }
```

when I deploy my app on glassfish 3.1.2 I get a plain NPE at the first invocation of logger in my Loader bean. This makes me think that CDI invocation is not happening at all, but I sincerely cannon understand what I'm doing wrong.

So far my EAR structure is as follows:

```
       EAR
         |
         +---lib
         |     +--loader.jar
         |     +--utils.jar
         |     +--log4j.xx.jar
         |
         +--MyStatelessSessionBean.jar
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some inconsistencies between your text and the structure of your EAR, i.e. you talk about a `utils.jar` but there is no such .jar in your EAR structure diagram.

Nonetheless, you mention that your `@EJB` is packaged inside `loader.jar` which in turn is in the `/lib` folder of your EAR. Since `loader.jar` is your `ejb-jar` it shouldn't be under `/lib`, but should be at the top level of your EAR.

In the `application.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
    <module>
        <ejb>loader.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    ...
    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

Hopefully this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question right away. Well actually I'm going to have two EJBs, a stateless session bean (MyStatelessSessionBean.jar) and my singleton stateless bean (loader.jar). I'll try to give this setup a try and post back here asap. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What actually solved the issue, was packaging my loader in a dynamic web app (thus moving it at EAR-root level) and leaving my utils.jar lib in the EAR/lib folder. Actually the application.xml is optional and, for the moment I'd like to leave it out for simplicity. I will try to create a jar-packaged loader but for the moment I'll go on with the war-packaged one. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Either archive type should work and you're right that `application.xml` is optional. Glad it helped though.